# simple aspx page, client side input and ssrs report viewer control

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

i am trying to use some html input controls (instead of the asp.net server controls) to capture input for a report's parameters and would like to post the parameter values to a ReportViewer control, and load the report from Report Server.

do i have to simulate a postback to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the values need to get to the server-side somehow, right? Or is this an AJAX implementation?

If you're using manual <FORM> POSTs instead of ASP.NET-based postbacks, you can still grab the form parameters from the Request.Form collection. Ie: `ServerControl1.ParameterToSet = ValidateInput(Request.Form["input1"])`.

(And make sure to validate the input still! That's what the ValidateInput method hint was for above.)  ;-)